# Need help understanding act and process for the definition of communication?

Tags: nouns, linguistics, dictionaries, abstract-nouns

When I looked up the word "communication" at www.dictionary.com, it gave the following meaning below:

1. the act or process of communicating; fact of being communicated.

My question is based on the meaning above, can you please give me a sentence example when the word "communication" is being used as an act and when it is being used as a process?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an act:

> Unfortunately, I have to engage in communication with my coworkers.

And here is a process:

> However, it is through this communication that we actually get things done.

I think the difference is quite subtle and, in most cases, not worth worrying about.